# determine the values of $x$ for the matrix below

Tags: linear-algebra

> $$
> A=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> x  & -1 & 0\\
> -1 &  x &  -1\\
>  0 & -1 &  x \\
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

The matrix above is a 3-by-3 invertible matrix ,find the values of x

Comment: What have you tried? Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematics formatting, and read especially [this post about matrices](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5023/15500).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When is the determinant not zero?  When $x \notin \{0,\sqrt 2,-\sqrt 2 \}$, right?

Comment: Ur right, but can you help me with the working up-to the answer

Comment: Use the formula for the determinant of a matrix. apply it to this matrix and set the determinant to zero.